# Sum of unique combinations of pairs in R

Tags: r

I have the `data.frame`:

```
tmp <- data.frame(C1=c(1,1,2),C2=c(2,3,3), CS=c(5,7,9))
> tmp
  C1 C2 CS
1 1  2  5
2 1  3  7
3 2  3  9
```

I need compute the sums to all unique combinations of pairs from the `data.frame`, where `C1` and `C2` are define the combinations of pairs, and  `CS` defines two terms for the sum. In common case the `nrow(tmp)` equal to `n`.

1st combination, the common number is **1**: (**1** and 2) and (**1** and 3) gives  5+7=12.

2nd combination, the common number is **2**: (1 and **2**) and (**2** and 3) gives  5+9=14.

3rd combination, the common number is **3**: (1 and **3**) and (2 and **3**) gives  7+9=16.

Expected results is the vector (12, 14, 16).

Could some one give an idea how to organize the full bust of all unique combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure why one would want to do something like this. There would have to be a better way to store that data. Anyway...

```
library(dplyr)

## create an accumulating list
output <- list()

## for each 'common number', find the rows (slice) for which that number
## is either in the first or second column, then sum the value of 
## CS in those columns.
for (pairNo in 1:3) {
  output[[pairNo]] <- tmp %>% 
    slice(which(pairNo== C1 | pairNo== C2)) %>% 
    summarise(pairNo=pairNo, result=sum(CS))
}

## > output
## [[1]]
## pairNo result
## 1      1     12
## 
## [[2]]
## pairNo result
## 1      2     14
## 
## [[3]]
## pairNo result
## 1      3     16
```

Cleaner output of that list is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Make a long dataset via `stack` or `melt` then `aggregate` or `tapply` or `dplyr` or `data.table` it to sum by group. One attempt in base R:

```
long <- cbind(tmp["CS"], stack(tmp[c("C1","C2")]))
long

#  CS values ind
#1  5      1  C1
#2  7      1  C1
#3  9      2  C1
#4  5      2  C2
#5  7      3  C2
#6  9      3  C2

with( long, tapply(CS, values, sum) )
# 1  2  3 
#12 14 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily better, but perhaps a little cleaner than my other answer;

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tmp %>% 
  gather(CS, "common") %>% 
  data.frame %>% ## avoids the duplicated name from a simple gather
  select(-CS.1) %>% 
  group_by(common) %>% 
  summarise(sum(CS))

##   common sum(CS)
## 1      1      12
## 2      2      14
## 3      3      16
```